# How to convert mm-dd-yyyy hh:mm string to a unix timestamp?

Tags: datetime

```
$time_str = '2013-09-03 03:29:11' ;

preg_match('/([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+) (.*)/', $time_str, $matches);
$new_str = $matches[3] . '-' . $matches[1] . '-' . $matches[2] . ' ' . $matches[4];
```

When I check the value of $new_str I get

```
$new_str = 03-2013-09 03:29:11
```

but when I check the value of `strtotime($new_str)` I get an empty value for $str
where `$str = strtotime($new_str)`

Comment: Is the format of `$new_str`correct as in MM-YYYY-DD, does it need to be in a different format for `strtotime`?

Comment: Actually I get this as output should use some date_format function to change it

Comment: It might help as the compiler might be confused with the format but I thought it would throw an exception. Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891937/strtotime-doesnt-work-with-dd-mm-yyyy-format

Answer (score 0):

to convert mm-dd-yyyy hh:mm string to a unix timestamp you can use `strtotime`

For more, findout [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8097922/convert-string-to-time-in-php) here